# JNI - How to generate header files for OSGI bundle

Tags: java, maven, java-native-interface, osgi

I made several very simple examples with Java and C using JNI. Usually after every Java code compilation C header files must be "extracted" and included into the C source code file and then compiled using gcc. My question is how I can generate C header files from OSGI bundle with Java code?

Can this be done during the bundle compilation time?

Answer (score 1):

You could automate header extraction with the [Maven JAVAH plug-in](http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-native/native-maven-plugin/javah-mojo.html). It should even be possible to use wild-cards to process an entire package.